# CP maps obeying an equality

Tags: oa.operator-algebras

Start with a completely positive unital map $\psi:A\to B$ between $C^*$ algebras with identity. The equality $\psi(a^*a)=\psi(a)^*\psi(a)$ is true for all $a\in A$ in the case where $\psi$ is a star algebra map. Are there cases where $\psi$ satisfies this without being an algebra map (I would guess so). In this case, what can be said about the cp maps?

This question arose in studying Hilbert $C^*$-bimodules and their properties. For a general such cp map there would be a Hilbert $C^*$ $A$-$B$-bimodule which was a quotient of $A\otimes B$ by null vectors for a certain inner product (the KSGNS construction). The condition given is (I think!!) the necessary and sufficient condition that the bimodule is a quotient of $B$.

Comment: It's been a while since I thought about these things, but does this follow from Choi's theorem on multiplicative domains (Theorem 3.19 in Paulsen's "Completely Bounded..." book)? It says that (for any $A$, $B$, and CP unital map $\psi$), the set of $a$ for which $\psi(a)^*\psi(a) = \psi(a^*a)$ and $\psi(a)\psi(a)^* = \psi(aa^*)$ is a $C^*$-subalgebra of $A$ and $\psi$ is a $*$-homomorphism ($=$ "star algebra map"?) when restricted to that $C^*$-subalgebra.

Comment: I was just about to say that this is a special case of M.D Choi's result (no relation) but @NathanielJohnston beat me to it. Like Nathaniel, I think I first saw this in Paulsen's book.

Comment: In fact, one has a slightly sharper statement: if $\psi : A\to B$ is UCP and some *particular* $a\in A$ satisfies $\psi(a^*a)=\psi(a)^*\psi(a)$, then $\psi(ba)=\psi(b)\psi(a)$ for all $b\in A$.

Comment: Many thanks - both those comments are very useful.